# Monitor Details in Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, driver, monitor, touchscreen

My friend has recently bought a second-hand vehicle with an in-car computer and it's wired up to a touchscreen monitor on the dashboard (very impressive!). Now, I've helped him install Ubuntu on it today but we can't establish the make and model of the connected touchscreen monitor to try and source the drivers to make the touchscreen function work.

Are there any Linux commands to work out the make / model of an attached monitor? I've tried Google which pointed me towards the /etc/X11 directory but have had no joy with that.

Comment: Have you considered asking this on AskUbuntu?

Comment: Will try there now @Ken. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you happen to be able to start an X11 server, you could try to run `xdpyinfo` and `xrandr` and look into the log of the Xorg server, probably in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`